# No implicit conversion between int and string

Tags: c#, .net, implicit-conversion

When i try to execute this belo code i'm getting that error.

//Code:

```
 int Value = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Value"] == null ? 0 : Request.QueryString["Value"]);
```

So i need to pass the value '0' if the `QueryString` value is null.

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pass the string `"0"` but a better way would be:

```
int Value = Request.QueryString["Value"] == null ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Value"]);
```

and you could also factor out the lookup:

```
string str = Request.QueryString["Value"];
int value = str == null ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(str);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
int Value = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Value"] ?? "0");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
int Value = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Value"] == null ? "0" : Request.QueryString["Value"]);
```

Or take the advantage of `??` operator

```
int Value = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Value"] ?? "0");
```

Your false and true statement in Ternary operator should be of same type or should be implicitly convertible to another.

> Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.

Taken from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int i;
int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["Value"], out i);
```

if parsing will fail `i` will have default value (0) without explicit assignment and checking if query string is null.

Comment: If the string is not a valid number, but also not `null`, then I think throwing an exception is much better than returning `0`.

Comment: @svick "So i need to pass the value '0' if the QueryString value is null."